# Using paths in javascript assets in rails 3.1.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I have a file called `myjavascript.js.erb` in my assets path. This is where I put all my project related javascript etc.

As I understand it, rails runs this file through the erb interpreter first and then loads the resulting JS file.

I have the following line in my file

```
console.log( "<%= root_path %>" );
```

I was hoping that this would log the root path of the project but unfortunately it seems to only get me

```
"/path to rails project omitted/app/assets/javascripts"
```

Surely this should point to the root of my project? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Rails.root
```

To get to the root path in Rails.

Comment: I see. What about the path to the index action of one of my controllers?

Comment: I think it would be "/users/index" or something.

I'm not too certain about that at the moment. Might want to make a separate question for that. Does my post fully answer your first question?

Comment: It's okay to ask lots of questions on here. I may not have the answer to the other one, but I'm sure someone does :)